# Capture group of HTML5 video screenshots

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-video

I am trying to generate a group of thumbnails in the browser out of a HTML5 video using canvas with this code:

```
        var fps = video_model.getFps(); //frames per second, comes from another script
        var start = shot.getStart(); //start time of capture, comes from another script
        var end = shot.getEnd(); //end time of capture, comes from another script

        for(var i = start; i <= end; i += 50){  //capture every 50 frames
            video.get(0).currentTime = i / fps;

            var capture = $(document.createElement("canvas"))
                .attr({
                    id: video.get(0).currentTime + "sec",
                    width: video.get(0).videoWidth,
                    height: video.get(0).videoHeight
                })

            var ctx = capture.get(0).getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(video.get(0), 0, 0, video.get(0).videoWidth, video.get(0).videoHeight);

            $("body").append(capture, " ");

        }
```

The the amount of captures is correct, but the problem is that in Chrome all the canvases appear black and in Firefox they always show the same image.

Maybe the problem is that the loop is too fast to let the canvases be painted, but I read that .drawImage() is asynchronous, therefore, in theory, it should let the canvases be painted before jumping to the next line.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of fighting with this I finally came up with a solution based on the "seeked" event. For this to work, the video must be completely loaded:

The code goes like this:

```
        var fps = video_model.getFps(); //screenshot data, comes from another script
        var start = shot.getStart();
        var end = shot.getEnd();


        video.get(0).currentTime = start/fps; //make the video jump to the start


        video.on("seeked", function(){ //when the time is seeked, capture screenshot
            setTimeout( //the trick is in giving the canvas a little time to be created and painted, 500ms should be enough
                function(){
                    if( video.get(0).currentTime <= end/fps ){

                        var capture = $(document.createElement("canvas")) //create canvas element on the fly
                        .attr({
                            id: video.get(0).currentTime + "sec",
                            width: video.get(0).videoWidth,
                            height: video.get(0).videoHeight
                        })
                        .appendTo("body");

                        var ctx = capture.get(0).getContext("2d"); //paint canvas
                        ctx.drawImage(video.get(0), 0, 0, video.get(0).videoWidth, video.get(0).videoHeight);

                        if(video.get(0).currentTime + 50/fps > end/fps){
                            video.off("seeked"); //if last screenshot was captured, unbind
                        }else{
                              video.get(0).currentTime += 50/fps; //capture every 50 frames
                        }


                    }
                }
                , 500); //timeout of 500ms


        });
```

This has worked for me in Chrome and Firefox, I've read that the seeked event can be buggy  in some version of particular browsers.

Hope this can be useful to anybody. If anyone comes up with a cleaner, better solution, it would be nice to see it.